# Adafruit LED Backpack with Windows 10 core

Tags: gpio, windows-iot

I have purchased the 4-digit 0.54" 14-segment Alphanumeric (https://www.adafruit.com/products/1911). I noticed there are helper classes for Python and Ardunio, but there isn't anything for Windows 10 IOT.

**C++** https://github.com/Adafruit/Adafruit-LED-Backpack-Library

**Python** https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_LED_Backpack/blob/master/Adafruit_LED_Backpack/AlphaNum4.py

Has anyone got any experience with this or can point me in the right direction.

I found the below on I2C on https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PinMappingsRPi2.htm

I've updated the connection settings to the same as I can see in the python script. I'm not sure what bytes I should be writing out to display letters and characters. Can anyone give me any pointers on this please?

```
public async void I2C()
{
    // Get a selector string for bus "I2C1"
    string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");

    // Find the I2C bus controller with our selector string
    var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    if (dis.Count == 0)
        return; // bus not found

    // 0x40 is the I2C device address
    var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x70);

    // Create an I2cDevice with our selected bus controller and I2C settings
    using (I2cDevice device = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings))
    {
        byte[] writeBuf = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
        device.Write(writeBuf);
    }
}
```

I have found this for the 4 digit 7 segment display

writei2c (0x00, 0x06, 0xff, 0x5b, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4f, 0xff, 0x66)   'Now, display "1 2 3 4"

http://www.picaxeforum.co.uk/showthread.php?26028-Programming-Adafruit-4-Digit-Displa7-(HT16K33)

Could you give me an example of the equivalent how to write 1 2 3 4 on the alphanumeric display please?

Comment: May I suggest you un-tag "raspbian" as this is specifically a "windows-iot" question - it *might* help others to focus on this particular question...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I write a character to the display basically

Comment: Found some documentation on the 4 digit 7 segment display. writei2c (0x00, 0x06, 0xff, 0x5b, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4f, 0xff, 0x66) which displays 1 2 3 4. Trying to find out how to write 1 2 3 4 on the alpha numeric display

Answer (score 1):

I have written a library to work with this display.

https://github.com/sobek1985/Adafruit_LEDBackpack

```
var alpha = new AlphaNumericFourCharacters(0x70);
alpha.ClearDisplay();
alpha.SetBlinkRate(0);
alpha.SetBrightness(1);
alpha.WriteCharacters(5,4,4,3);
alpha.WriteDisplay();
```